# R: Are there directory-specific r profile files?

Tags: r

I know of site-wide and user-specific .rprofile files that are loaded on startup, but is there any way to do something like have a similar file that only is loaded when the current working directory is the directory of the file?

RStudio's Project feature does something like this, but I don't want to use projects.

Comment: Are you running R from the command line or are you running from RStudio or the base R GUI? What operating system are you using? If running from the command line R will look for a .Rprofile file in the directory you are in when you launch R.

Comment: RStudio, Windows 10. Yes, I know I can have it look for a .Rprofile file in the directory for launching R and it will otherwise look for the file in the R root directory, but I'm interested in it looking *every time I change the current working directory.*

Comment: No. That's not a thing R does. R will not try to find an .Rprofile file every time you change the working directory. If you need something like that, you should write your own function that will both change the working directory and look for a file with a certain name in the directory and `source()` if is exists.